# Qt can't assign value to QLabel

Tags: c++, qt

I like to start out saying that I'm about as noob as they come. This is my first c++ program I built from scratch. I gotten most of the bugs ironed out, however I can't seem to be able to assign a value to a QLabel. I want the function 'value' to be called when the calculate button is pressed. The function 'value' should then do math and return the answer which is then assigned to the QLabel 'results'. Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QString>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QComboBox>
double x;

double value(QSpinBox *spinner)
{
int speed;
speed = spinner->value();
x = speed/8;

return x;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{




QApplication prog(argc, argv);


QWidget *mainWindow = new QWidget;
mainWindow->setWindowTitle("Plex Calculator");

QPushButton *calculate = new QPushButton("Calculate");
QComboBox *kbormb = new QComboBox;
QSpinBox *spinner =new QSpinBox;
QSlider *slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
QLabel *results = new QLabel;

spinner->setRange(1,1000);
slider->setRange(1,1000);
spinner->setValue(1);

QObject::connect(spinner, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),slider, SLOT(setValue(int)));
QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),spinner, SLOT(setValue(int)));


kbormb->addItem("kb/s");
kbormb->addItem("mb/s");

QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;

layout->addWidget(slider);
layout->addWidget(spinner);
layout->addWidget(kbormb);
layout->addWidget(calculate);
layout->addWidget(results);

QObject::connect(calculate, SIGNAL(clicked()), &prog, SLOT(results->setNum(value(*spinner));));


mainWindow->setLayout(layout);
mainWindow->show();

return prog.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with following signal slot connection.

```
QObject::connect(calculate, SIGNAL(clicked()), &prog, SLOT(results->setNum(value(*spinner));));
```

You are trying to connect the `clicked()` signal of `calculate` button to `results->setNum(value(*spinner));` slot of `prog`. But `results->setNum(value(*spinner));` is not actually a slot.

A slot is simply a method in a class that inherits `QObject`. Method should be added under `slots:` section in the class. Read more about signals and slots [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

To fix this, you will have to create a separate class for your widget and add the logic their. you can add a slot to the newly created class and connect the `clicked()` signal to that. Then you can do the calculation in the slot.